# Unclear on how to import and display an .OBJ file with Python (in Maya)

Tags: python, import, external, maya

I've been working on a project for a week now trying different ways to solve this.  I'm extremely new to python and programming in general and don't know the basics.

The task is to make a window with a button that imports an external .obj file into the scene and rename it.  At one point I was able to do that by putting the files in the "HOME" directory aka My Documents but I lost that piece of code.

I've tried tons of ways but I don't understand the correct syntax at all. I've asked classmates for help as well and we couldn't figure out where to store the obj and how to reference it properly.

I see this thread which seems useful but always returns "No files found" [Importing OBJ file to maya scene (MEL/Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675233/importing-obj-file-to-maya-scene-mel-python).

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import os

ram = mc.window("RenamerWin", t = "Renamer v 1.0", w = 300, h = 300)
if mc.window(ram, exists = True): 
    mc.deleteUI("RenamerWin")

#icon
logopath = mc.internalVar(upd = True) + "icons/icon.jpg"

mc.columnLayout(adj = True)
mc.image (w = 300, h = 100, image = logopath)
mc.separator (h = 25, style = 'double')

mc.text("Welcome to your Custom Forest Builder!")

rockW = mc.intSliderGrp(l = "width", min = 0, max = 10, field = True)
rockH = mc.intSliderGrp(l = "height", min = 0, max = 10, field = True)
rockD = mc.intSliderGrp(l = "depth", min = 0, max = 10, field = True)
mc.button(l = "Create a Rock", c = "myRock()")

#Name the Rock
rockName = mc.textFieldGrp (l="renamer", editable = True)
mc.button (l = "Name the Rock", c = "myRockRenamer()")
mc.showWindow(ram)
def myRockRenamer():
    finalName = mc.textFieldGrp(rockName,q = True, text = True) 
    mc.rename(finalName)

mc.showWindow(ram)

def myRock():
    myRockWidth = mc.intSliderGrp(rockW, q = True, value = True)
    myRockHeight = mc.intSliderGrp(rockH, q = True, value = True)
    myRockDepth = mc.intSliderGrp(rockD, q = True, value = True)
    finalRock = mc.file(os.path.join(os.getenv('E:\2015\2. Tech Art Programming\Forest Builder'), 'rock.obj'), open = True, force = True)
    finalRock.scale( myRockWidth, myRockHeight, myRockDepth)
```

Questions:

1. Do I store the .obj in the same folder as the .mb file? I want to be able to zip this code.
2. Do I have to load the file into maya first then use another piece of code to display it?
3. Can you link me to some references?  I've searched google over and over again.  maybe I've stumbled across the answer but didn't understand what I was looking at.
4. How to I store this other than in the maya folder on my PC?

   logopath = mc.internalVar(upd = True) + "icons/icon.jpg"
5. When I get the window to open and try to press the button I don't get an error about the file not being found anymore (I did before).

"# Error: TypeError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\bin\python27.zip\ntpath.py line 96: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

Thank you SO much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your problem is that you can't auto-find the path to your obj, or you can't get it to import/rename afterwards?
I've just made a quick example of how I would do it:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
new_name = "Renamed_OBJ"
my_file_path = "C:/Temp/OBJ_Temp.obj"
import_nodes = cmds.file(my_file_path,i=True,type="OBJ",rpr="OBJ_Import",rnn=True)
transform_nodes = cmds.ls(import_nodes,type="transform")
for t_node in transform_nodes:
    print(t_node)
    cmds.rename(t_node,new_name)
```

A few things; You can use i=True + type="OBJ" in the file command to import objs and add rnn=True to get it to return all the nodes it just imported.
Then you can sort through them a pick out the transform nodes, and rename and scales those.
This documentation helps me a lot in times like this: https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/?guid=__CommandsPython_index_html

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't escaping the backslashes in your file path, so maya sees them as special chararacters.  Try

```
    finalRock = mc.file(os.path.join(os.getenv('E:\\2015\\2. Tech Art Programming\\Forest Builder'), 'rock.obj'), open = True, force = True)
```

or

```
    finalRock = mc.file(os.path.join(os.getenv('E:/2015/2. Tech Art Programming/Forest Builder'), 'rock.obj'), open = True, force = True)
```